# calling cancelAllOperations from nested NSOperations

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm struggling with the following situation, pleaes bear with me as I've tried to be explain this as clearly as possible:

I have a class CoummintyOperation which is a subclass of a GroupOperation. CommuityOperation is called and added to an NSOperationQueue.
CommunityOperation is in turn calling a whole bunch of NSOperations which are also sublcasses of GroupOperation and in turn are calling NSoperations within them.
I've added dependencies for the GroupOperations in the CommunityOperation class. 
The issue I'm dealing with is if a nested operation fails I need to cancel ALL NSOperations in the CommunityOperations class, but I don't have access to the operationQueue that CommunityOperation was added to in order to call the cancelAllOperations method.

Can anyone help me out and explain how I can call this method, cancel All operations in this class (and therefore all nested Operations) and display an error message to the user.

Thanks in advance

Here's some sample code to help explain my issue:
CommunityOperation gets put on an operationQueue from another class (not included)

```
public class CommunityOperation: GroupOperation {

    var updateOperation: UpdateOperation!
    var menuOperation: MenuOperation!
    var coreDataSaveOperation: CoreDataSaveOperation!

    var hasErrors = false

    public init() {

        super.init(operations: [])

        updateOperation = UpdateOperation()
        menuOperation = MenuOperation()
        coreDataSaveOperation = CoreDataSaveOperation()
        coreDataSaveOperation.addDependencies([updateOperation, menuOperation])

        self.addOperation(updateOperation)
        self.addOperation(menuOperation)
        self.addOperation(coreDataSaveOperation)
    }
}
```

MenuOperation class, which has nested Operations in it as well:

```
class UpdateMenuOperation: GroupOperation {

    let downloadGroupsOperation: DownloadGroupsOperation
    let downloadMembersOperation: DownloadMembersOperation

    init() {
            downloadGroupsOperation = DownloadGroupsOperation()
            downloadMembersOperation = DownloadMembersOperation(])

            super.init(operations: [downloadGroupsOperation,
                downloadMembersOperation
                ])
        }
}
```

DownloadGroupOperation class is again a subclass of GroupOperation. It has 2 operations - the first to download data and the second to parse the data:

```
class DownloadTopGroupsOperation: GroupOperation {
    let downloadOperation: DownloadOperation
    let importTopGroupsOperation: ImportOperation

    init() {
        downloadOperation = DownloadOperation()
        importOperation = ImportOperation()
        importOperation.addDependency(downloadOperation)
        importOperation.addCondition(NoCancelledDependencies())

        super.init(operations: [downloadOperation, importOperation])
    }
}
```

And finally (whew) the DownloadOperation class uses a NSURLSession and the method `downloadTaskWithURL`, it's in this method's completion handler that I want to call cancelAllOperations on the main operatioQueue if an error is returned:

```
class DownloadOperation: GroupOperation {
    init() {
        super.init(operations: [])
        if self.cancelled {
            return
       }
        let task = session.downloadTaskWithURL(url) { [weak self] url, response, error in
            self?.downloadFinished(url, response: response as? NSHTTPURLResponse, error: error)
        }
    }

    func downloadFinished(url: NSURL?, response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, error: NSError?) {

       if error {
         *cancel allOperations on queue*
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Source code would help. Can you put together a brief example of what you are doing?

Comment: @Dominic any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It should work in a bit different way. I'd check the `isCancelled` from the `GroupOperation` by the end of each `NSOperation` execution. If operation was cancelled then cancel the current `GroupOperation` and so on. In the end your `CommunityOperation` should be cancelled as well.

Here is the rough implementation of the proposed solution:

```
extension GroupOperation {

    func addCancellationObservers() {
        self.operations.forEach() { $0.willCancelObservers.append() {  [unowned self] operation, errors in
            self.cancel() // cancel the group operation. will force it to cancel all child operations
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then call `addCancellationObservers` from the `init` method of each group operations you have.

Comment: could you give an example please, I'm not following what you're saying. I've updated my question with code.

Comment: The GroupOperations class doesn't have an operations array variable

Comment: Are you using self-written `GroupOperations` or custom solution like https://github.com/danthorpe/Operations ?

Comment: It's from Apple's NSOperations sample code (https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2015/?q=nsoperations)

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Apple's sample code (or https://github.com/danthorpe/Operations which is the evolution of that project) you can sort this out by attaching a condition to your operations which have dependencies.

Here is the init of your top level `GroupOperation`

```
init() {

    updateOperation = UpdateOperation()
    menuOperation = MenuOperation()
    coreDataSaveOperation = CoreDataSaveOperation()
    coreDataSaveOperation.addDependencies([updateOperation, menuOperation])

    // Attach a condition to ensure that all dependencies succeeded
    coreDataSaveOperation.addCondition(NoFailedDependenciesCondition())

    super.init(operations: [updateOperation, menuOperation, coreDataSaveOperation])
}
```

To explain what is happening here... `NSOperation` has no concept of "failure". The operations always "finish" but whether they finished successfully or failed does not affect how `NSOperation` dependencies work.

In other words, an operation will become ready when all of its dependencies finish, regardless of whether those dependencies succeeded. This is because "success" and "failure" is something that the subclass must define. `Operation` (the `NSOperation` subclass) defines success by having finished without any errors.

To deal with this, add a condition that no dependencies must have failed. In Operations this condition got renamed to make it clearer. But, the concept exists in the Apple sample code too.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation @DaneilThorpe. I figured out what you mentioned above but your putting so concisely really helps. Basically my current solution is in the `operationDidFinish:WithErrors` methods for my operations, if it finishes with an error I'm using NSNotifiications to call the `operationQueue.cancelAllOperations()` method on the class that created the operation queue (obviously this isn't an elegant solution but it seems to be working).

Comment: With regards to the second part of your answer, I'm not clear on where and what to add such that if a dependancy has failed all subsequent operations on the queue should cancel. Can you shed some light on that please. (I downloaded your Operations project)    Thanks

Comment: @Daniel.Thorpe if one of the nested operations (e.g. DownloadOperation) was cancelled due to  a cancelObserver, how would I cancel all operations originating from the main class?

Comment: Adding the `NoFailedDependciesCondition()` to the last operation of the top level Group Operation doesn't seem to provide the correct behaviour for ALL the nested operations in the other GroupOperation classes as per my example.